# Changes not occur unless main.scss is saved | SASS

Tags: sass, node-sass

I have main.scss file that imports all other scss files. But whenever I make changes in "pages/band" file, no changes occur unless I save main.scss everytime. 
I'm running live-server

EDIT:
Here is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap_startup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Bootstrap startup",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"
  },
  "author": "Zain",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0"
  }
}
```

main.scss

```
@import "abstract/mixins";
@import "abstract/variables";

@import "base/animations";
@import "base/base";
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/utilities";

@import "components/cards";
@import "components/footer";

@import "pages/band";
@import "pages/home";
```

Comment: How is your build script setup? What compiles the scss to css?

Comment: check my edited description

Answer (score 1):

For any kind of auto refresh functionality to work on a packaged local server solution, your tool is always going to need to know what files to watch for changes.

`live-server` is the same way. You need to tell it what files to watch for updates. When you initialize `live-server` [you can use the `--watch=PATH` flag to tell it what files to watch for updates](https://github.com/tapio/live-server#usage-from-command-line).

Answer (score 1):

I found that after you adding a new @include in main.scss file you must restart once sass compiler script so that it fetch the changes to it. It works for me.

Comment: yep....good call alex.....I can live with this solution